# Capital Only Edit Control

Tags: wix

Having a bit of a problem doing this and not sure of it can be done. I have an edit control that a user types into, I would like for the input to be all in capital letters. I tried having a custom action on the edit control to get the property, convert to capital letters and set the property again each time a letter is set but it does not work. I guessed it wouldn't but no harm in trying..:)

Has anyone else solved this? I would like to do it without having a button to press if possible. The dialog in question is a twin dialog if that helps at all.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the native built-in Windows Installer UI.  The underlying [MaskedEdit Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is primitive.  There are no events to tie into to validate and modify as the characters are entered.  You can only ToUpper() the property when the user clicks Back or Next.

The alternative would be to go with an external UI handler which is a lot of learning and work.

Comment: Thank you, the ToUpper function was the one I had implemented :) Thanks for the clarification.